# Collision Detection In Android

Tags: android, collision-detection

Ok, so whats the best way to detect collisions in Android? The only examples I can find on it all involves finding when the two objects are directly over each other. Personally I was thinking about using bounding boxes, but even that I do not know how to do, and then I still desire something a little more precise (per-pixel?).

Comment: Box2d is a library .. it will make your life easier

Answer (score 3):

edthethird is almost right.

You want to use to `myRectHitbox.intersect(myOtherRectHitbox)` instead of `. contains(...)`. `.contains(...)` will only tigger if the one Rect is completely inside another but `.intersect(...)` triggers if there is any pixel that overlaps another.

And if you use `RectF` instead of `Rect` you will get subpixel accuracy on devices that support subpixels.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not an expert on this subject, I recommend you to use the Box2d library to do it. It is a very complete physics engine with very good support for collisions detection.

Useful link: http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/

Comment: Mhmm I've heard about this libary before but have been wondering if you can use it soley for calculating collisions as i have no need for the physics in it

Answer (score 1):

Two Steps:

1. Give everything that can collide a "hitbox".  Keep a `Rect` in your objects, the same size as the drawable and at the same place.
2. Call one of the three `myRectHitbox.contains(...)`.  You can check collisions on points or rects this way.